# How to validate image, date, checkbox and radio button in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, validation, radio-button, ng-pattern

How to validate image, date, checkbox and radio button in **angular.js**? What is `ng-pattern` for checkbox, radio button, image and date or good plugin available for validation?

How to add `validator.rule` for these fields?

Comment: Please revise your question: do you want to know, how angularjs validation works like minlength, maxlength and custom validators or do you want to use other validation mechanism?

Comment: check out $pristone , $invalid , $dirty , $invalid if you want to get through validation , ps please revise your question

Comment: @kamelMili , how validate image on submit ?